# Chrome Prerender feature gets canceled every time

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, prerender

I'm trying the prerender feature in chrome, but when I check the network, I can see the request is beeing canceled for any link.

[image: chrome developer console]

I'm using the following syntax:

```xml
<link rel="prerender" href="http://example.org/index.html">
```

I tried the live demo at http://prerender-test.appspot.com/ and got the same result.
Why is that?

Update (from [https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/prerender](https://web.archive.org/web/20131216173035/https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/prerender)):

In some cases while prerendering a site Chrome may run into a situation that could potentially lead to user-visible behavior that is incorrect. In those cases, the prerender will be silently aborted. Some of these cases include:

- Note: This is not an exhaustive list. Last updated 11/10/11.

  1. The URL initiates a download
  2. HTMLAudio or Video in the page
  3. POST, PUT, and DELETE XMLHTTPRequests
  4. HTTP Authentication
  5. HTTPS pages
  6. Pages that trigger the malware warning
  7. Popup/window creation
  8. Detection of high resource utilization
  9. Developer Tools is open
  10. Plugins such as Flash will have their initialization deferred until the user actually    visits the prerendered page.

But the question is when **can** I use this feature?

Comment: Does the demo say that you have prerender ENABLED?

Comment: sure, otherwise it won't let you enter a link

Comment: The demo's working for me. Have you tried on different machines?

Comment: will try now, could it be a firewall issue? (trying from work)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In this case it sounds like the prerender requests are being canceled because you have Developer Tools open.

If you want to see more information about the reason why the requests are being canceled, copy and paste chrome://net-internals/#prerender into your omnibox and hit enter.

Prerendering should work in almost all cases that *aren't* listed in the list of cancellation reasons that you pasted from the whitepaper.

Comment: Why is prerender disabled if Developer Tools is open?

Comment: This leads to a sort of perverse situation - how do I know if prefetch is working when developer tools are closed? Does a prefetched resource actually prefetch if no one is watching? Faith, I suppose.

Comment: If developer tools is causing it to not work then I'd recommend using something external to your browser (like Fiddler) to check if your prefetch is working.

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/prerender?csw=1#debug maybe?

Comment: This is because pre-rendering of a web page happens in a separate background tab (with no dev tools attached) and when you visit the pre-rendered page, the browser switches the tab (all in the background) and contents of this tab have already been rendered without the dev tools open. Hence, since you require devtools for that page the browser loads it again.

Answer (score 1):

## Prerender, Prefetching & Developer Tools:

Prerender And Prefetching Links ( That are not the same features at all ) are disabled when developers tools are open (in most of browsers: IE, Chrome, Firefox) because they are both partly based on "Cache" - Actually "prefetch" is totally based on Cache and sub-resources Because that's what it does - it loads the Future content ( Top Layer only ) to the cache so it will be already available when navigating to the next page.
"prerender" uses cache but Also Renders the entire Page into a "hidden Tab" in the background.

When Enabling the Dev Tools the current page is not "Caching" because most of the browsers disables cache by default when dev tools are open.

To see the Prerendering in action and to test it The best method is to use the Task Manager - You will be able to see a Prerender Process Kicking in once the current page is loaded.

All you need To know about Prerender / Prefetching Summarized: **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26519065/1486486)**