# Will HTML Prefetching Also Start Downloading Streaming Content?

Tags: html, streaming, prefetch

Prefetching is one of the new standards that make up HTML5. You can add it to tags like this:

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="/images/big.jpeg">
```

My questions:

1. What happens if you try and prefetch a page with streaming data, like Youtube? Will the video start buffering?
2. Does it matter what the content is (Flash vs HTML5 video for example)? I ask this because [this FAQ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Link_prefetching_FAQ) mentions that only HTTP/S will be prefetched.

Comment: Ok, since no one is answering I guess it is research time.

Comment: I think that it is up to the browser implementation. I had made some research in the pas and this is where it led me.

Comment: I found this question talking about Chrome's implementation a bit:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973992/chrome-prerender-feature-gets-canceled-every-time

Comment: @JimmyKane Thanks for the answer. I guess you are right and this is (unfortunately) not standardized. I'll leave the question open and maybe in the future there will be a definite answer.